# location button not pointing me to my location in google map api v2

Tags: android, gps, maps, location

google map is displying perfectly and googleplayservices are also present,
but my location button on top right corner is not working in google maps api v2 my wifi and gps both are on.Kindly help.
i am testing it on my handset.
I dont know why its not working

**mainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mapexample;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
    private GoogleMap myMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (myMap == null) {

            myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
  // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (myMap != null) {
                // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.
                setUpMap();
            }
        }

    }


    @Override
     protected void onResume() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onResume();

      int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

      if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }else{
       GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
      }

     }


    private void setUpMap(){
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

}
```

mainifest file is here with proper permissions.
**mainfest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapexample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapexample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapexample.MainMenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapexample.MainActivity">
         </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapexample.ATMlist">
         </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY KEY HERE" />
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: your code is working fine.. location button is pointing

Comment: I have the same problem, do you resolve it?

And the problem appears some device, not all.

Comment: yes sometime it works and some time its not...
I hve learnt somewhere its gps.. which some time takes time to get exact location...
and sometime unable to point out the location...

Answer (score 1):

Try turning GPS satellites off in Location access settings. If it's enabled but GPS can't be reached, the my location button fails silently; by turning it off it apparently forces the feature to use the network provider.